# HK Airport Express free return ride?

Tags: transit, public-transport, hong-kong

I have a 10-hour layover in HK soon and I plan to explore the city. I read [on the MTR website](https://www.mtr.com.hk/en/customer/services/complom_return.html) that same-day return rides on the Airport Express are free. I'm wondering how I can redeem this. Do I need to pre-purchase the ticket online, or should I have an Octopus ready and preloaded on my phone?

Also, will I have any luck using an Amex card in stores and restaurants in downtown/central HK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you should buy a same-day return ticket from either the counter or the vending machines. Having a physical Octopus preloaded with some cash could work too: this could also help you take the MTR, the tram, possibly buses without having to purchase tickets. Both options are eligible for the free return ride.

As for American Express cards, they are quite common in HK – surely not as much as Visa and MasterCard, but living here, I've had a couple over the years, issued by HK banks. Smaller shops might not accept them, but I've never had any issue.